# Why did Mike leave?

Tags: character, casting, suits

I don't think Mike's character should have vanished like what the creator showed in *Suits*. While it is true that Meghan Markle is now Duchess of Sussex and probably can't work (or something), the audience truly loved Mike individually.

There could have been a replacement of Rachel, or a dramatic break-up, maybe. The audience would have gulped the heart-breaking news like that. But simply erasing Mike was not really good.

Now if we logically think, when you move to another city, you don't totally vanish like that. Especially with the expertise of Mike Ross.

Did the creators really have to let go of Mike because of Rachel? I don't think his character was so dependent on hers. Or, was there other reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [this interview in the *Hollywood Reporter*](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/suits-patrick-j-adams-exit-interview-why-is-patrick-j-adams-leaving-suits-1079602), Patrick J. Adams, who plays Mike Ross, explains that he chose to leave the show **because he believed Mike Ross' story had nowhere else to go:**

> As we were starting to talk about renegotiating contracts [for season eight and beyond], I took a moment. Everybody was going full steam ahead and I stopped and said, "We need to think about this because this is more of my time and more of my life — and what’s the story left to tell?" [...] I had this voice in my head that said that we've told his story and if he hangs out longer, Mike is just going to be another lawyer on television. That didn’t feel right for him.

Whether you agree with him is another matter entirely, but that is why he left.

As far as I can tell, Meghan Markle's own departure from the show had nothing to do with Adams' departure. It was just convenient timing for the writers, as it allowed them to write them both out at the same time.

For the record, Adams has not ruled out returning to the show in future, even if it's just a one-off:

> I’ve said my goodbyes to Mike and to *Suits*, but I never close any door. When the time comes, if it felt like [returning] was the right thing to do, I’d definitely be open to it. [...] If it felt like it was the appropriate thing to bring Mike back for a big goodbye, then that’s something I could be open to.